# using gmail send message api with uploadType=resumable

Tags: google-api-python-client

I need to send email with large attachment using resumable upload type with gmail python client api.

This mode is supported by client for google drive as described here:
[uploading files to gdrive](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/manage-uploads)

Does the google-api-python-client support this option for send message in gmail or do I need to implement it as described here:[send message with resumable upload](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/guides/uploads#resumable)

Answer (score 0):

In order to use google-api-python-client to send emails with large attachments do the following:

create message object as described [here](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/guides/sending#creating_messages_with_attachments) but instead of encoding the message write the message to file and use send_message api as follows:

```
    message = (service.users().messages().send(userId=user_id, body=None, media_body=file_name)
           .execute())
```

Comment: Could you provide an example?